# Ruby: Undefined method

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I am having an issue with my first ruby program with hashes. I get an error saying

> 'throw': Undefined local variable or method 'directions' for .......

#### **Here is the code:**

```
class Die

  directions = {

      north: 1,
      south: 2,
      east: 3,
      west: 4
  }
    def throw

      direction = directions.select{ |key ,value | value == rand(4)+1}
      puts direction

    end
end

 Dice = Die.new
 Dice.throw
```

## **Question 1**

How how I fix this error?

## **Question 2**

Ruby-mine has a zig-zag line under the hash directions and gives the option to remove the assigment why is this?

## **Question 3**

There is also a zig-zag under 'key' and offers to convert it to "to do block" why is this ?

Comment: Please take more care in writing your question, it's full of typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It has to do with scopes. A method body runs in the scope/context of the instance, but the class definition runs in its own scope. You could use instance variables and initialize the hash as `@directions` in the initialize method, but in your case the hash will probably not change, so I recommend using a constant. In Ruby these are declared just like variables, but when the first character is uppercase, they are constants.
2. Probably because the variable is never used, for the reasons detailed in (1)
3. `key` is also never used, you can ignore it by using a variable name that starts with an underscore (`_key`) or just an underscore will also do. I like to use the first form, so I know what's in there when I come back later to this piece of code.
4. It probably wants you to convert it to a block because of better readability.

Full code:

```
class Die
  DIRECTIONS = {

      north: 1,
      south: 2,
      east: 3,
      west: 4
  }

  def throw
    direction = DIRECTIONS.select do |_key, value|
      value == rand(4)+1
    end
    puts direction
  end
end
```